# Data constructor in template haskell

Tags: haskell, template-haskell

I'm trying to create the ring Z/n (like normal arithmetic, but modulo some integer). An example instance is Z4:

```
instance Additive.C Z4 where
  zero = Z4 0
  (Z4 x) + (Z4 y) = Z4 $ (x + y) `mod` 4
```

And so on for the ring. I'd like to be able to quickly generate these things, and I think the way to do it is with template haskell. Ideally I'd like to just go `$(makeZ 4)` and have it spit out the code for `Z4` like I defined above.

I'm having a lot of trouble with this though. When I do `genData n = [d| data $n = $n Integer]` I get "parse error in data/newtype declaration". It does work if I don't use variables though: `[d| data Z5 = Z5 Integer |]`, which must mean that I'm doing something weird with the variables. I'm not sure what though; I tried constructing them via newName and that didn't seem to work either.

Can anyone help me with what's going on here?

Comment: I'm not a Template Haskell wizard, but I'm betting the people who are will want to see your Template Haskell code.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The [Template Haskell documentation](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.2.1/html/users_guide/template-haskell.html#id712116) lists the things you are allowed to splice.

> A splice can occur in place of
>
> - an expression; the spliced expression must have type `Q Exp`
> - an type; the spliced expression must have type `Q Typ`
> - a list of top-level declarations; the spliced expression must have type `Q [Dec]`

In both occurrences of `$n`, however, you're trying to splice a *name*.

This means you can't do this using quotations and splices. You'll have to build declaration using the various combinators available in the `Language.Haskell.TH` module.

I think this should be equivalent to what you're trying to do.

```
genData :: Name -> Q [Dec]
genData n = fmap (:[]) $ dataD (cxt []) n []
                           [normalC n [strictType notStrict [t| Integer |]]] []
```

Yep, it's a bit ugly, but there you go. To use this, call it with a fresh name, e.g.

```
$(genData (mkName "Z5"))
```

Comment: Could you include an example of its use? I modified what you had slightly and just threw `$(genData "Foo")` as a top-level into my code, but if I do `:i Foo` in ghci it doesn't find anything.

Comment: @Xodarap: Use `mkName` to make a `Name` from a `String`. I've added an example. I guess you may have used `newName`, which adds some stuff at the end to ensure that the name is unique, so `:info` would not show it. You should be able to see it using `:browse`, though.

Comment: Thanks! this was my problem exactly.